# How to get the next enum value from an enum in protobuf?

Tags: c++, enums, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I have a protobuf message with non-consecutive enum values something like this:

```
message Information {
    enum Versions {
        version1 = 0;
        version2 = 1;
        version3 = 10;
        version4 = 20;   
        version5 = 30;    
    }
}
```

I want to have a C++ function GetNextVersion() which takes in one enum version and gives the next version as output. For eg: GetNextVersion(Information::version4) should give Information::version5 as output. Is there any inbuilt and easy method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use protobuf's reflection to achieve the goal:

```
Information::Versions GetNextVersion(Information::Versions ver) {
    const auto *desc = Information::Versions_descriptor();
    auto cur_idx = desc->FindValueByNumber(ver)->index();
    if (cur_idx >= desc->value_count() - 1) {
        throw runtime_error("no next enum");
    }

    auto next_idx = cur_idx + 1;
    return Information::Versions(desc->value(next_idx)->number());
}

int main() {
    try {
        auto ver = Information::version1;
        while (true) {
            cout << ver << endl;
            ver = GetNextVersion(ver);
        }
    } catch (const runtime_error &e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any inbuilt and easy method to do this?

#### I see no easy method to get that.

But I can suggest [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approaches (at least on Linux) with C++ code generation.

You could, assuming you have access to the [source code of *protobuf-c*](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c) :

- write some [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) script to parse that C++ code and generate the C++ code of `GetNextVersion`
- perhaps write some [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) (or a [Python](https://python.org/) one) script doing the same.
- write some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) and use it to parse that C++ code and generate the C++ code of `GetNextVersion`
- write some [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) code doing the same.
- wait a few months and (in spring 2021) use [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/). I am developing it, so contact me by email
- extend and adapt the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) for your needs.
- extend and adapt the [SWIG](https://swig.org/) tool for your needs.
- extend and adapt the [RPGGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN) tool for your needs.
- use [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) to parse C++ code, or design your [domain specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) with some *documented* [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) syntax and write some code generator with them.

You could also keep the description of `enum Versions` in some database ([sqlite](https://sqlite.org/), [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/), etc...) or some [JSON](https://json.org/) file or some [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file (or an [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) one, using [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) or [libexpat](https://libexpat.github.io/)) and emit it (for protobuf) and the source code of `GetNextVersion` using some [Python](https://python.org/) script, or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp).

You could write a [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script or some [rules for CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) generating some C++ code with your protobuf description.

In a few months (spring 2021), the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) system might be helpful. Before that, you could contribute and extend it and reuse it for your needs.

A pragmatic approach could be to add a comment in your protobuf declaration to remind you of editing another file when you need to change the protobuf message and protocol.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

You define your own data type, so you also must define the operators for it.

So, your GetNextVersion()method contains that knowledge how to increment the version number.  If you had decided to use an integer, then the compiler knows already how to increment that, but you wanted something special and that is the price you have to pay for it.